# I can't pass this error : cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a json file myself.**I'm throwing my json file as an image because I can't find how to attach it below.**

[image]

What I am trying to do is to display the contacts in my json file and filter after each character I type in the search field.

```js
const nameList = document.querySelector('.nameList');
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
const path = "db.json";
let respData = [];


async function getUsers(path) {
  const resp = await fetch(path);
  respData = await resp.json();
  displayData(respData);
}
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  const filteredData = respData.names.filter((character) => {
    return (
      character.author.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
    );
  })
  console.log(filteredData);
  displayData(filteredData)
});


const displayData = (users) => {
  const htmlString = users.names.map((user) => {

    return `
        <ul> 
            <li class="character">
                <img class="image" src="/img/profile.png"></img>
                <p class="name">${user.author}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        `;
  }).join("");
  nameList.innerHTML = htmlString;
}
getUsers(path);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #111d4a;
}

.container {
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container h1 {
  color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.container #searchWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.container #searchWrapper #searchBar {
  width: 90%;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.container #searchWrapper::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 30px;
}

.container .nameList {
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (minmax(320px, 1fr))[auto-fit];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.container .nameList ul .character {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'name image' 'house image';
  text-align: left;
}

.container .nameList ul .character .image {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-height: 100px;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-row-span: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-area: image;
}

.container .nameList ul .character p {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  grid-area: house;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -18px;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=index.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>&#x2728;Name List &#x2728;</h1>
    <div id="searchWrapper">
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="searchBar" id="searchBar" placeholder="search for a name" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <ul class="nameList"></ul>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**and the result on my screen is exactly like this I can't get past this error**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filteredData` variable after filtering names doesn't contain property `names` and that is why you are getting the "trying to access a member of undefined" error. Consider passing names array directly to the `displayData` function and then calling the `map()` function on that passed argument.